# Casting object to array - any magic method being called?

Tags: php, arrays, object, casting

I have an object of class Foo:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    protected $a;
    protected $b;
}

$obj = new Foo();
```

What I want (and have) to do is cast this object to an array, like this:

```
$arr = (array)$obj;
```

Is there any magic (or not magic :)) method that is being called at this moment? Or is there any other way to intercept it? I know I can write a simple method, eg. `asArray()` in Foo, but I'm looking for some more "native" PHP ways.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can have the class implement the [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.  This will allow you to treat the object like an array without casting and you get total control over how the members are used.

Comment: Though nice, this answer doesn't really address the question. You should at least include the word "no" in there somewhere :)

Comment: Good point, but state somewhere at the beginning of the answer that implementing the `ArrayAccess` interface is not sufficient to cast an object to an array.

Comment: Should also be noted that in order to loop over elements contained within the object that extends `ArrayAccess` using `foreach`, you must also implement `\IteratorAggregate` or `\Iterator`. Generally those looking to reproduce array functionality within an object use `implements \Countable, \IteratorAggregate, \ArrayAccess` See [\ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php).

Answer (score 52):

### No

There is no `__toArray` magic method in PHP. An [enhancement proposal has been rejected](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38508) in **2006** with the following answer:

> [2006-08-20 11:12 UTC] helly@php.net
>
> Why not simply have a method asArray() maybe even as par of an
>   interface:
>
> interface ArrayConversion {   function asArray(); }
>
> See, we have __toString as it is supported in language constructs like
>   echo, print and other internal functions. But we decided against an
>   autoconversion for arrays already. So itwill never be supported in any
>   language construct. That said there is no needed for this and nothing
>   you would win against the above interface. In fact you would make it
>   php more complex because you'd add just one more magic feature.

It is thus very unlikely that it will be implemented in any future release (which is a pity, if you ask me).

Comment: but hey, didn't we get the goto construct at least? *shivers*

Comment: It's strange he should say so, cause actually php has an object to array convertion: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Comment: The question is actually about being able to implement custom casting logic.

Comment: Just a note: In 2019, PHP is now discussing __toArray() : https://wiki.php.net/rfc/to-array

Answer (score 15):

Sadly no, casting to array doesn't trigger any magic method like it is done with:

```
$s = (string)$obj;
```

which triggers `__toString()` method and which you can override.

However, you may write a custom `toArray()` method.

You may also be interested in the [`Serializable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface which allows you to write custom serializer strategy.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this question still relevant, but php has builtin [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class, that allows to treat object as array and can be handy when used as container for database record or collection.

It might be not a best practice in regards to strict types, but it allows to treat object as array and both statements are valid.

```
$obj = new ArrayObject(['a' => 'alpha']);
var_dump($obj['a']); //alpha
var_dump($obj->getOffset('a'));//alpha
```

However you need to keep in mind behaviour of `ArrayObject`

```
$obj = new ArrayObject(['a' => 'alpha']);
//Access Property
var_dump($obj['a']); //alpha
var_dump($obj->offsetGet('a'));//alpha
var_dump($obj->a); //null Notice: Undefined property: ArrayObject::$a

//Serialization
var_dump(serialize($obj));// string 'C:11:"ArrayObject":41:{x:i:0;a:1:{s:1:"a";s:5:"alpha";};m:a:0:{}}' (length=65)
var_dump($obj->serialize());// string 'x:i:0;a:1:{s:1:"a";s:5:"alpha";};m:a:0:{}'
var_dump(serialize($obj) === $obj->serialize());// false !!!

//Setting Properties
$obj['b'] = 'beta'; //OK
$obj->c = 'gamma'; //value becomes object property!!!
var_dump($obj);
/* OBJECT DUMP
object(ArrayObject)[13]
  public 'c' => string 'gamma' (length=5)
  private 'storage' =>
    array (size=2)
      'a' => string 'alpha' (length=5)
      'b' => string 'beta' (length=4)
 */

//Property validation as array
var_dump(isset($obj['a']));//true
var_dump(isset($obj['b']));//true
var_dump(isset($obj['c']));//false
//Property validation as object
var_dump(isset($obj->a));//false
var_dump(isset($obj->b));//false
var_dump(isset($obj->c));//true

//Typecasting
var_dump((array)$obj);
/*
array (size=2)
  'a' => string 'alpha' (length=5)
  'b' => string 'beta' (length=4)
 */

//var_dump((string)$obj);// Catchable fatal error: Object of class ArrayObject could not be converted to string
```

ArrayObject accepts two flags `ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST` as default and `ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS` as alternative.

This would change behaviour for reading values but does not support setting new properties in that way, here is example:

```
$obj = new ArrayObject(['a' => 'alpha'], ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
//Access Property
var_dump($obj['a']); //alpha
var_dump($obj->offsetGet('a'));//alpha
var_dump($obj->a);//alpha

//Serialization
var_dump(serialize($obj));// string 'C:11:"ArrayObject":41:{x:i:0;a:1:{s:1:"a";s:5:"alpha";};m:a:0:{}}' (length=65)
var_dump($obj->serialize());// string 'x:i:0;a:1:{s:1:"a";s:5:"alpha";};m:a:0:{}'
var_dump(serialize($obj) === $obj->serialize());// false !!!

//Setting Properties
$obj['b'] = 'beta'; //OK
$obj->c = 'gamma'; //OK
var_dump($obj);
/* OBJECT DUMP
object(ArrayObject)[14]
  private 'storage' =>
    array (size=3)
      'a' => string 'alpha' (length=5)
      'b' => string 'beta' (length=4)
      'c' => string 'gamma' (length=5)
 */

//Property validation as array
var_dump(isset($obj['a']));//true
var_dump(isset($obj['b']));//true
var_dump(isset($obj['c']));//false !!!
//Property validation as object
var_dump(isset($obj->a));//true
var_dump(isset($obj->b));//true
var_dump(isset($obj->c));//true

//Typecasting
var_dump((array)$obj);
/*
array (size=2)
  'a' => string 'alpha' (length=5)
  'b' => string 'beta' (length=4)
 */
```

To make this behaviour more consistent you would have to extend this class and implement magic methods `__get()`, `__set()`, `__isset()` and `__unset()`.

Another tricky part is serialization, default method `serialize` would return you a copy serialized `$storage` variable instead of object itself, as workaround to return serialized copy of instance you can implement default serialization in `__toString` method, this way it's behave correctly.

```
class FooObject extends ArrayObject
{
    public function __get($index)
    {
        if ($this->offsetExists($index)) {
            return $this->offsetGet($index);
        } else {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Undefined key ' . $index);
        }
    }

    public function __set($index, $value)
    {
        $this->offsetSet($index, $value);
        return $this;
    }

    public function __isset($index)
    {
        return $this->offsetExists($index);
    }

    public function __unset($index)
    {
        return $this->offsetUnset($index);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return serialize($this);
    }
}
```

Example of usage

```
$obj2 = new FooObject(['a' => 'alpha']);
//Access Property
var_dump($obj2['a']); //alpha
var_dump($obj2->offsetGet('a'));//alpha
var_dump($obj2->a); //alpha

//Serialization
var_dump(serialize($obj));// string 'C:11:"ArrayObject":41:{x:i:0;a:1:{s:1:"a";s:5:"alpha";};m:a:0:{}}' (length=65)
var_dump($obj->serialize());// string 'x:i:0;a:1:{s:1:"a";s:5:"alpha";};m:a:0:{}'
var_dump(serialize($obj) === $obj->serialize());// false !!!

//Setting Properties
$obj2['b'] = 'beta'; //OK
$obj2->c = 'gamma'; //OK
var_dump($obj2);
/* OBJECT DUMP
object(FooObject)[14]
  private 'storage' (ArrayObject) =>
    array (size=3)
      'a' => string 'alpha' (length=5)
      'b' => string 'beta' (length=4)
      'c' => string 'gamma' (length=5)
 */

//Property validation as array
var_dump(isset($obj2['a']));//true
var_dump(isset($obj2['b']));//true
var_dump(isset($obj2['c']));//true
//Property validation as object
var_dump(isset($obj2->a));//true
var_dump(isset($obj2->b));//true
var_dump(isset($obj2->c));//true

//Typecasting
var_dump((array)$obj2);
/*
array (size=3)
  'a' => string 'alpha' (length=5)
  'b' => string 'beta' (length=4)
  'c' => string 'gamma' (length=5)
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this, without changing the original class definition is to use reflection. This allows to you examine the class's properties at runtime.

Taken from the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public    $foo  = 1;
    protected $bar  = 2;
    private   $baz  = 3;
}

$foo = new Foo();

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    print $prop->getName() . "\n";
}

var_dump($props);

?>

The above example will output something similar to:
foo
bar
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(ReflectionProperty)#3 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    ["class"]=>
    string(3) "Foo"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(ReflectionProperty)#4 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    ["class"]=>
    string(3) "Foo"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_object_vars($yourObject) that will return an associative array of all property names/values accessible from the context.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

A you want to access protected or private properties, my advice would be to extend ArrayObject, that implements the method getArrayCopy()