# PHP: serialize as array an object via (array) $object

Tags: php, arrays, object

Is there a way to serialize an object into an array when this code is called:

```
class Obj {
    private $prop;
    public function __construct($v) {
       $this->prop = $v;
    }
}

$object = new Obj('value');
$result = (array) $object;

print_r($result);

// should display something like Array ( prop => value )
// via a magic function call in the object ?
```

Some ArrayObject, Traversable and other stuff can help using objects inside foreach, count() and the like. But with the force-typed array syntax, what can we do?

Thanks

EDIT
I found this post which was a question better explained thant mine :)
[Casting object to array - any magic method being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121613/casting-object-to-array-any-magic-method-being-called)

The answer is: no, you can't ask for a magic method when calling (array)$object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) ignores visibility declarations when called from the right scope:

```
class Obj {
    private $prop;
    public function __construct($v) {
        $this->prop = $v;
    }
    public function asArray() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}

$object = new Obj('value');
$result = $object->asArray();

print_r($result); // Array([prop] => value)
```

Comment: ok, so there's nothing like `function __clone()` for `clone $object`. For example, `function __toArray()` for `(array) $object`

Comment: You mean, like `__toString` for arrays? No, there's no such thing, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but the property `prop` is private so when you try to print will return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Objprop] => value
)
```

In order to return `prop` as key you should make your property public
or you can make getter function:

```
public function getV(){
     return $this->v;
}
```